# Rapid question on minimal normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Why does $N$ finite group, $M\unlhd N$ imply that $M$ contains a minimal **normal** subgroup of $N$?

If $M$ is itself minimal in $N$ we have finished. But if not, we know that there exists a minimal subgroup $P\stackrel{min}{\le}N$ s.t. $P\le M\le N$. But why, among such $P\;$'s, can we find one of them which is normal in $N$?

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition for "minimal normal subgroup"? As far as I know, it is a subgroup which does not contain a proper nontrivial subgroup that is normal in $N$. Now what if $M$ is not minimal?

Comment: Yes: a minimal normal subgroup of $N$ is a normal subgroup $P$ s.t. if $Q\unlhd N$ and $Q\le P$ then $Q=P$. And: what if $M$ is not minimal? There exists a subgroup of $N$ contained in $M$! All clear, I'm tired. Thanks sanktoras!

Comment: What if M is trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While any subgroup of a finite group contains a minimal subgroup, a normal subgroup doesn't necessarily contain a subgroup that is both minimal and normal. Such a subgroup would be called a *normal minimal subgroup*. If you reverse the two adjectives and speak instead of *minimal normal subgroups* you are talking about something else: you are talking about subgroups which are minimal **among** normal subgroups. Now the fact should be clear: the collection of nontrivial normal subgroups of a finite group will be finite, nonempty and partially ordered (by inclusion) + in any finite partially ordered set, every element is greater than some minimal element.

Comment: Hence you said that, given $G$ a finite group we can consider two different cases:1) the set of minimal subgroups of $G$; if among these there exists a normal subgroup it will be a **normal minimal subgroup** of $G$. Otherwise we can consider 2) the set of normal subgroups of $G$; taking a minimal element of these we get a **minimal normal subgroup**. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Yep. ${}{}$